# Can't map Azure drive storage as netword drive using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm first testing the connection to the storage over port 445:

> Test-NetConnection -ComputerName myshare.file.core.windows.net -Port
>   445
>
> ComputerName     : myshare.file.core.windows.net 
>   RemoteAddress    : 55.111.11.152 
>   RemotePort       : 445 
>   InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet 
>   SourceAddress    : 192.168.47.204 
>   TcpTestSucceeded : True

So, everything seems OK, buth then:

> New-PSDrive -Name F -Persist -PSProvider FileSystem -Root
>   "\\myshare.file.core.windows.net\myfolder"
>
> New-PSDrive : The network name cannot be found At line:1 char:1
>   + New-PSDrive -Name G -Persist -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\myshare ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (G:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], Win32Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand

Any ideas?

Comment: May I know the PS version?  Workstation service was set to manual and check

Comment: @SumanthMarigowda-MSFT Yes, of course, it's 5.1.14393.2828

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, for future users desperate as I was, I found the solution. The value of registry key

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\lmcompatibilitylevel

must be set to 3. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a UNC path via add `\\`, it will be like this,

`New-PSDrive -Name F -Persist -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\myshare.file.core.windows.net\myfolder"`

I add the storage account credentials and map azure file share on windows server 2016 Azure VM.
[image]
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows#mount-the-azure-file-share-with-powershell

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I have a double slash in my script, but SO somehow hided it, I had escaped the code and added an extra back slash, and now it shows OK. But this is not the cause of my problem

Comment: Do you still get the error`New-PSDrive : The network name cannot be found At line:1 char:1 + New-PSDrive -Name G -Persist -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\myshare `?

Comment: It seems a temporary issue on your side. There can be a number of problems that can cause this - like a connection issue, adapter configuration etc. More details you could have a look at [this](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/04/UNC-Drive-Mapping-Failures-Network-name-cannot-be-found).

Comment: But I'm unable to determine the cause.. And what is more estrange, the first test is successful..

Comment: Then the error still exists? Could you describe it more details? Do you run it in a specific network environment like wireless wifi? Or the same error happened on another host in another network?

Comment: Yes, the same as in my post: New-PSDrive : The network name cannot be found
At line:1 char:1
+ New-PSDrive -Name F -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\myshare ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (F:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand

Comment: In order to narrow down the scope of this issue, you can try to run PS drive on another VM in the same network or another machine or VM in a different network. Make sure you have not any typo error like format, quotation marks, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help Nancy, I found the solution